# Coordinates from create grid

Tags: qgis, vector-grid

I am setting up a hectare grid in QGIS 3.0 using **Vector > research tools > create grid > grid type:point** and then defining boundaries by a preexisting polygon layer. I would like to get coordinates from these points but the x and y axis created seem to be defined not by the CRS but by seemingly arbitrary numbers. Is there a way I can get coordinates into the attribute table? When I identify feature, I can find the actual lat/long coordinates but I cannot figure out how to import these into the attribute table.

Comment: What CRS is the point grid layer in?

Comment: I have tested, and i have the goods x, y attributs in the fields "left" and "top". This fields are automaticaly created whis the tool "create grid". Are you sure you have choose the same CRS as your project when you created the point layer?

Answer (score 3):

1. Open the attribute table
2. Add two fields: X and Y in the attribute table with a Decimal Number (real) type, and length 10
3. Select the X field from the drop-down menu, write in the expression `$X` and click on update all
4. Select the Y field from the drop-down menu, write in the expression `$Y` and click on update all
5. Save edits and stop editing.

[image]